# addView causes crash in my android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I've already searched for similar threads, but I couldn't find any solution to my problem.
Here is my main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mt);
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv.addView(ll);
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_mt);
        //layout.addView(ll);
        layout.addView(sv);
        setContentView(layout);
```

I also added `id` to my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity_mt"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MtActivity" >
```

But whenever I try to run my app, it crashes. Where is the problem?

Comment: Post your logcat then..

Comment: @MD logcat gives me nothing

Comment: @AJ If your app getting crashed then definitively logcat generated with logss..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
  RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_mt)
```

with

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_mt)
```

findViewById looks up for an value into `R.id`, not in `R.layout`

Answer (score 2):

You got confused with `R.id.activity_mt` and `R.layout.activity_mt`because you named them same. Just replace the line

`RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_mt)`

with

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_mt)
```

Previously, it was storing `null` in `layout`, that is why is was throwing `nullpointerexception`. But after doing it, everything will be cool.